# How do I migrate my code for the Google VR SDK for Android?

Tags: google-vr

I have an existing Android app using the Cardboard SDK. How do I migrate my code for the Google VR SDK for Android?

Answer (score 1):

In general, packages have been migrated from `com.google.vrtoolkit.*` to `com.google.vr.sdk.*`. The `com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard` package is now now `com.google.vr.sdk.base`.

Top-level `Cardboard`-prefixed classes have also been renamed and are now `Gvr`-prefixed:

- `CardboardActivity` -> `GvrActivity`
- `CardboardView` -> `GvrView`
- `CardboardAudioEngine` -> `GvrAudioEngine`

The SDK library name has changed:

- `core.aar` -> `base.aar`

Finally, the following `GvrView` methods have been removed:

- `setRestoreGLStateEnabled` (disabled always)
- `setVignetteEnabled` (enabled always)
- `setGyroBiasEstimationEnabled` (enabled always)

Comment: will this work for the scripts in Unity as well, or was the overall structure of the plugin altered?

Comment: Structure of the Unity plugin is the same.  Some classes and their instance pointers have been renamed.  For instance, "Cardboard.SDK" is now "GvrViewer.Instance".